# Пытаюсь создать миграцию (python manage.py makemigrations).Django 3.1

Tags: python, django

Доброго времени суток всем!

Прошу помощи. Пытаюсь создать миграцию (python manage.py makemigrations), а он мне отвечает:

```
no changes detected
```

Как быть?
Что я уже пробовал и не получилось:

Проверял есть ли в списке `installed_apps` в `settings`.
Пытался через `python manage.py makemigrations YOUR_APP_NAME`
Пересоздавал проект :)))
Прошу помочь, ибо устал уже.

P.S. Некоторые говорят, что надо удалить БД, но я слишком зеленый и не особо понимаю как, зачем и почему.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

mysql python django

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class Category(models.Model):
    #категории

    name = models.CharField('категории', max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField('описание')
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'категории'
        verbose_name = 'категори'



class Actor(models.Model):
    #Actor

    name = models.CharField('имя', max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('возраст', default=0)
    description = models.TextField('описание')
    image = models.ImageField('изоюражение', upload_to='actor/')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Актёры и режисёры'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Актёры и режисёры'


class Ganre(models.Model):
    #жанры

    name = models.CharField('имы', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('описание')
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'жанры'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Жанры'



class Movie(models.Model):
    #film
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    tagline = models.CharField('Слоган', max_length=100, default='')
    description = models.TextField('описание')
    poster = models.ImageField('постер', upload_to='movies/')
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('дата выхода', default=2019)
    country = models.CharField('страна', max_length=30)
    directors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, verbose_name='актеры', related_name='film_director')
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, verbose_name='актёры', related_name='film_actor')
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Ganre, verbose_name="жанры")
    world_premiere = models.DateField('примьера в мире ', default=date.today)
    budget = models.PositiveIntegerField("Бюджет", default=0,
                                         help_text="указывать сумму в долларах")
    fees_in_usa = models.PositiveIntegerField('Сборы в США', default=0, help_text='указывать сумму в доларах')

category = models.ForeignKey(
        
        Category, verbose_name="Категория", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
        
        )
    
        

url = models.SlugField(max_length=160,unique=True)
draft = models.BooleanField('черновик', default=False)



def __str__(self):
    return self.title

  

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'фильм'
    verbose_name_plural = 'фильм'






class MovieShots(models.Model):
    #кадры из фильма
    title = models.CharField('заголовок', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField('изображение', upload_to='movie_shots/')
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, verbose_name='Фильм', on_delete=models.CASCADE)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'кадры из фильма'
    verbose_name_plural = 'кадры из фильма'











class RatingStar(models.Model):
    #звезда рейтинга
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('значение', default=0)



def __str__(self):
    return self.value

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'звезда рейтинга'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Звёзды рейтинга'




class Rating(models.Model):
    #рейтинг
    ip = models. CharField('IP адрес', max_length=15)
    star = models.ForeignKey(RatingStar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='звёзда')
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CharField, verbose_name='фильм')
    




def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.star} - {self.movie}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'рейтинг'
        verbose_name_plural = 'рейтинги'    




class Reviews(models.Model):
    #отзывы
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField('имя', max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField('Сообщение', max_length=5000)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(

       'self', verbose_name='родитель',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True

        )

    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, verbose_name='фильм', on_delete=models.CASCADE)



    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}-{self.movie}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'отзыв'
        verbose_name_plural = 'отзывы'
```

Comment: а вы изменения в модели вносили?)

Comment: @Totall Man попробуйте `python manage.py migrate --fake app_name zero` не забудьте поменять `app_name` на свое приложение. После чего выполните `python manage.py migrate app_name`

Comment: да вносил, после введения  python manage.py migrate --fake app_name zero выдаёт App 'film' does not have migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю вы создали модели и вам нужно сделать миграцию?Просто пропишите python manage.py migrate , если вы выполняли уже эту команду,то сделайте python manage.py makemigrations(без лишних строк,просто python manage.py makemigrations) ,а потом опять python manage.py migrate

Comment: Если не помогло - напишите!

Comment: не помогло,с python manage.py makemigrations выдаёт-no changes detected

Comment: а с python manage.py migrate выдаёт-Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: С makemigrations выдаёт - что не обнаружено изменений,а у вас есть модели?Ну даже не знаю,попробуйте удалить ваши модели(закомментировать),потом сделать python manage.py makemigrations и потом python manage.py migrate,потом вернуть модели и сделать тоже самое(python manage.py makemigrations,потом python manage.py migrate).

Comment: C:\django\film>py manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

C:\django\film>py manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

Comment: я удалил и тоже самое

Comment: Покажите файл models.py пожалуйста!(отправьте код в вопрос)

Comment: я выложил код т

Comment: Ну в принципе ошибок там нет...Но только вопрос,почему некоторые классы Meta не под классам с моделью?Ну а так,даже не знаю...Можно удалить папку migrations,да попробуйте сделать это,т,е удалить папку с миграциями потом python manage.py migrate